# AWS ECS Fargate stopped logging but is still running

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I made a Django app on AWS ECS Fargate with Load Balancer. The flask app is simple server that returns *'this is an index page.'*
the ECS checks health every 5 minutes. And these health checks recorded on a log page of the service.

So I launched this app at 0:20, and the log page recorded the health check correctly. But the log page stop logging at 4:00. Nobody accessed the page, status of the service is *healthy* and I checked the setting of health check but there was nothing that could be a problem I think.

[Here is the image of the logs. (when stopped)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0TMk.png)

After that, I entered the app, accessed correctly and load balancer left records of that request. But log page of the ECS log page still stopped.

Do you have any idea about this problem?

---

**UPDATE**: I checked CloudWatch's log and it was working well! (I didn't know that..) But when cluster > service > log stopped, there is an error. (I had this problem several times and I checked the error is all the same)

The error is **Not Found: /latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document**

I searched and I figure out that the document is related to **instance identify**. How I can fix this error?

Comment: Are you talking about custom log page? Can you confirm of the service that is writing to log is running fine?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand 'custom log page', but log page that I told is "ECS > Cluster > Service > logs". And I think the service is running fine. I can't find any evidence that there are some problems.

Comment: did you check the logs in the cloudwatch

Comment: @ArunK Thank you! I checked cloudwatch. the problem is updated

Comment: can you check whether an IAM role is assigned to your ecs service/task

Comment: I also encountered this issue. it happens to our task once its processing a large concurrent request